# (Qualitative) Quantum explanation of simple electric phenomenon

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

Recently, I came across the following problem in some textbook,

> A current of $1 \,\text{mA}$ flows through a wire made of a piece of copper.
> and a piece of iron of identical cross-sections welded end-to-end as shown
> in the figure [*Added: There is a Cu wire and a Fe wire, having equal cross section, joined end to end*]. How much electric charge accumulates at the boundary between the two
> metals? How many elementary charges does this correspond to?

They used "standard" though unspecified numerical values values for the resistivity of each of the metals. There is minimal calculation anyway and one only has to use $\vec j=\sigma \vec E$ with Gauss' law . Now comes the main question:

> The values of $Q$ comes out to be $\approx 5\cdot 10^{-21}\approx\frac{1}{30}|e|$, i.e.,
> much smaller than the electronic charge, without any restriction on the size of the conductors.

They say a Quantum description is neceassary for explaining what happens at the surface. I'm only familiar with introductory QM, but well-versed with the classical EM theory. Is there a qualitative explanation of what actually happens? I'm willing for an explanation that might be hard to understand at the moment, but maybe after a year or so, one should get  the feeling "so it was that!".

*Edit in response to requests for clarity:*
I'm attaching the relevant pictures and roughly, trying to decode what the authors meant (at a simpler level).

[image: Problem figure]
[image: Picture of the phenomenon]
[image: Solution given in the textbook]

Comment: Regardless of quantumness, what particular feature of this is it that you want an explanation thereof?

Comment: I wanted to understand the nature of the deposited charge: whether it is a particular *smeared electron* (which doesn't look right as macroscopically it should move appropriately), something like a *bound charge* (which obviously does not look okay since classically it is supposed to be free) or maybe it does not hold exactly at all just statistically.

Comment: one needs details and clarity. Is there a link to the problem?

Comment: @annav I have tried to clarify a bit.

Comment: You need to clarify what the "known data " are. A is an area? so the numbers do depend on it?

Comment: I'm sorry, @annav but it is not nice of you to just close the question. I sent the pictures of the original question also and there no data is mentioned. In fact, they have also mentioned (in the photo) that only the current is necessary for finding net charge; area is irrelevant.

The known data probably refers  to resistivity as I mentioned and they have used some standard values (not given in the book). Known: current, resistivity. Their Q: intersurfacial charge. My Q: In what form does this surface charge physically exist/ can be thought to exist as classical description is inconsistent.

Comment: And wait, what do you mean by "A"? It's Ampere in standard SI notation not an area?!

Comment: This is a wonderful and fascinating question, especially with the clarifying info. There is not much to the quantum picture though, because it will just be about an electron being a wavefunction that is spread out widely and thinly, so that only a tiny part of the wavefunction "will be spending slightly more time there than elsewhere", that is able to explain the fraction of the charge despite charge being quantised. You can go into greater detail a few times, each with a monumentally greater improvement in understanding, but this is the jist of it. Voted to reopen.

Comment: I agree, this should be reopened. @MATHSMOD the conduction electrons in a metal are extended objects described approximately by [Bloch waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloch%27s_theorem). The excess at the junction just means the waves have a slightly higher amplitude there so it is less exciting than you think.

Comment: I suppose it is a human tendency to idealize something that is beyond one's control. And a bit of curiosity is enough to stay optimistic :) In general, I find the simplest electromagnetic phenomenon combined with quantization absolutely mind-blowing ("how could this even hold").

Comment: @mathsmod $A$ is area, check what is an electric flux in Gauss law ${ \Phi _{E}={\frac {Q}{\varepsilon _{0}}}}$. Namely its a dot product of electric field and surface normal :$ \Phi = \vec E \cdot  \vec S$. And if cross-section of Cu and Fe wires would be different, then boundary charge would be $Q=\epsilon_0 (A_1 E_1 - A_2 E_2) $

Comment: @AgniusVasiliauskas The original asker did not care to elaborate what they meant by A and you need not worry. Everyone at this level is well aware of these things and it was just a poor excuse for closing this maybe-weird question.

Comment: No, question is awesome - it shows the need and purpose of quantum mechanics. In a classical view, electrons stops a bit at metal junction and goes further. So Cu-Fe  joining section acts as a thin quantum well, aka potential barrier. It's like a horse who stops a bit before jumping a high barrier.